# Swift static content behind UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to implement static fullscreen view with some labels and buttons. Bellow this view should be a table with additional content.

What I need to implement is that scrolling above the static view will scroll the table, so the user will be able to bring the table content over the static view.

I tried to put an empty table cell with height of the screen to the table. This works, but the static cell was not able to interact with the tap events (buttons didn't work).

The same happens when I put empty view with the height of the screen as a header view of the table.

I've set .isUserInteractionEnabled to false in both cases. Didn't help

Comment: Have you tried with `isUserInteractionEnabled to true `?

Comment: I need the table view to be touch "transparent", so isUserInteractionEnabled should be false.

Comment: Can you show an image of what you want to do? Above, below, over, under, "bring the table content over the static view", etc get's very confusing. I *think* I will have a solution for you.